# proof that power set A union B doesnt equal powerset A union powerset union B

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Why is this equation: \begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(A \cup B) = \mathbb{P}(A) \cup \mathbb{P}(B)
\end{equation}

false with: $A = \{0\}$ and $B = \{1\}$?

Are they not both $\{ \emptyset,0,1\}$?

Comment: First note that $\mathbb{P} A = \{\,\emptyset, \{ 0 \}\,\}$ and not $\{\, \emptyset, 0\, \}$.  And also note that $\mathbb{P} A \cup B = \{\,\emptyset, \{ 0 \}, \{ 1 \}, \{ 0, 1 \}\,\}$

Comment: recall the definition of the power set: the power set is the set of all subsets, so what is wrong in your question?

Comment: I see, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. We have $P(A\cup B) = \{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{0,1\}\}$ but $P(A)\cup P(B) = \{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\} \}$, as $P(A) = \{\emptyset, \{0\}\}$ and $P(B) = \{\emptyset, \{1\}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, if a set $A$ is finite, then $|\mathbb{P}(A)|=2^{|A|}$.  In this case, that means that $\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)$ has $4$ elements.  The set you describe is $\mathbb{P}(A)\cup \mathbb{P}(B)$ which has only 3 elements (by inclusion-exclusion since $|A|\cap |B|=1$).